# Flutter Staggered Grid View

Tags: flutter, user-interface, gridview

I'm using StaggeredGridView plugin to create a gridview with some cards, and inside these cards, another gridview to show some data. I'm struggling to find a way to debug the blue card last (and a bit bigger) words. I think it would work if the blue card, instead of a square, becomes a rectangle, but I also couldn't find a way to do it (at least main/crossAxisSpacing method didn't solve).

[image: UI]

Here's the code snippet of the cards:

```
  Widget MainBody(){
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2,5,2,0),
        child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          itemCount: subsystems.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
            elevation: 2,
            color: subsystems[index].cardColor,
            //color: Colors.grey[200],
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: (){Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EntitiesPage(index.toInt())));},
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: Container( //starts here
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:5),
                        child: subsystemCardTitle(index),
                      ),
                      subsystemCardEntities(index)
                    ],
                  )
                ),
              ),
            )
          ),
          staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.fit(2),
          mainAxisSpacing: 0.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 0.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and the data inside the cards

```
  Widget subsystemCardEntities(int index){
    return  GridView.count(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      children: [
        for(var name in subsystems[index].entity)
          Center(child: Text(name))
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: If it is ok, you may reduce the number of columns in the grid where the length of words is big with crossAxisCount: 3, ?

Comment: well... works... but I rather solve this problem on the "right way" so I can learn to future problem solving ^^